WebSocket connection works perfectly in plain JavaScript, but it's not connecting in Node.js
I'm trying to connect to a WebSocket. The URL looks like this:
wss://xxx.xxx.com/public/time/player/test/xxx/socket?messageFormat=json&SESSIONID=xxx&instance=xxx&client_version=xxx
In JavaScript, it works perfectly, and I receive all messages. However, when I try the same in Node.js, it doesn't even connect.
I've already tried using different packages like websocket and wb, but none of them worked.
Here’s the code I used in plain JavaScript:
const socketUrl = 'wss://xxx.xxx.com/public/time/player/test/xxx/socket?messageFormat=json&SESSIONID=xxx&instance=xxx&client_version=xxx';

const socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);

socket.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("Connection opened:", event);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Message received:", event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
    console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
};

socket.onclose = function() {
    console.log("Connection closed");
};

Here’s the code I used in Node.js:
const socketUrl = 'wss://xxx.xxx.com/public/time/player/test/xxx/socket?messageFormat=json&SESSIONID=xxx&instance=xxx&client_version=xxx';

const WebSocket = require("ws");

const connect = () => {
  const socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
  
  // Stuck in CONNECTING
  socket.on("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to socket");
  });

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log("Received message:", data);
  });

  socket.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected from socket");
    connect();
  });

  socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Socket error:", err);
    socket.close();
  });
};

connect();

Here is an image the headers from a successful connection in plain JavaScript:
successful connection

What 'doesn't even connect' look like exactly? Share logs!

@Evert the readyState is always on CONNECTING I think it has to do something with the handshake

logs are important. I don't see how from your code you could know this, unless you used a debugger. Can you curl the endpoint from the server this Node instance is running on?

the readyState where is that shown?
